# Pandas - Searching for a particular text in entire Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that stores a particular text in multiple columns. I am trying to filter out all rows across the DataFrame that has this value.

```
id,col1,col2,col3,col4
1001,apple,banana,pear,kiwi
1002,,apple,,
1003,banana,kiwi,,
1004,pear,orange,apple,
```

Given the above sample, I am trying to filter all rows that have the word `apple` along with the id of that row.

```
for col in df:
    apple = df[df[col].astype(str).str.contains("apple")]
```

But this returned empty rows.

**Expected output:**

```
id,value
1001,apple
1002,apple
1004,apple
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Idea is set `id` to index and replace non `apple` values to missing by [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html), so after [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) get Series with `MultiIndex`, so add double [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) - first for remove first level and second for convert `Series` to `2 columns DataFrame`:

```
df = (df.set_index('id')
        .where(lambda x: x == 'apple')
        .stack()
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .reset_index(name='val')
)
print (df)
     id    val
0  1001  apple
1  1002  apple
2  1004  apple
```

For test substrings use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and remove missing rows by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df = (df.set_index('id')
        .stack()
        .where(lambda x: x.str.contains('apple'))
        .dropna()
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .reset_index(name='val')
)
print (df)
     id    val
0  1001  apple
1  1002  apple
2  1004  apple
```

Comment: This the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
for col in df:
    apple = df[df[col].astype(str).contains("apple")]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter out all rows with that string, why is it in your expected output only id of a row?
To filter out all rows with that string I would do it that way:

```
mask = None
for col in df.columns:
     mask_cur = df[col].astype(str).contains("apple")
     mask = mask_cur if mask is None else (mask & (mask_cur))
answer = df[mask]
```